# CIM_LogicalDisk enumerations

Tags: powershell, wmi

Can someone point me to a reference on the enumerations of DriveType & MediaType for CIM_LogicalDisk? I am pretty sure DriveType is the same as when using WMI and Win32_LogicalDisk, but I can't find any helpful info on the MediaType enumeration.

Comment: Lol, you are right Microsoft uses the buzz words [Media Type Enumeration](https://www.google.com/search?q=windows+MediaType+enumeration) inflationary. I did find a proper enumeration but without indices and alphabetically sorted :-(

Answer (score 2):

I found this for you:

`DriveType` enum:

```
Value    Meaning
--------------------------
0        Unknown
1        No Root Directory
2        Removable Disk
3        Local Disk
4        Network Drive
5        Compact Disc
6        RAM Disk
```

`MediaType` enum:

> Type of media currently present in the logical drive. This value will be one of the values of the MEDIA_TYPE enumeration defined in Winioctl.h.  The value may not be exact for removable drives if currently there is no media in the drive.

See [`_MEDIA_TYPE` Enumeration of `Ntdddisk.h`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/hardware/ff562216).

Comment: The `winioctl` documentation for that `enum` is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/desktop/api/winioctl/ne-winioctl-_media_type), although it doesn't explicitly list the member values.

Answer (score 0):

To get a verbose output of DriveType, insert your own `[enum]`

```
## Q:\Test\2018\07\27\SO_51558468.ps1

Enum DriveType {
  Unknown         = 0
  NoRootDirectory = 1
  RemovableDisk   = 2
  LocalDisk       = 3
  NetworkDrive    = 4
  OpticalDisk     = 5
  RamDisk         = 6
}

# need a calculated property to insert the Name of the enum
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_logicaldisk | 
  Select-Object DeviceID,
  @{n='DriveTypeVerbose';e={[enum]::GetName([DriveType],$_.DriveType)}},
  ProviderName,FreeSpace,Size,VolumeName | Format-Table

Get-WmiObject -Class CIM_logicaldisk | Where DriveType |
  Select-Object DeviceID,
  @{n='DriveTypeVerbose';e={[enum]::GetName([DriveType],$_.DriveType)}},
  ProviderName,FreeSpace,Size,VolumeName | Format-Table
```

Sample output

```
DeviceID DriveTypeVerbose ProviderName         FreeSpace          Size VolumeName
-------- ---------------- ------------         ---------          ---- ----------
A:       LocalDisk                            1049710592    1073737728 RamDisk
C:       LocalDisk                          926377299968  999176232960 System-HPG1610
D:       OpticalDisk
K:       NetworkDrive     \\xxxxx\c         105826541568  214276501504 System
L:       NetworkDrive     \\xxxxx\D        1065067708416 2000263573504 Data
Q:       NetworkDrive     \\yyyyyy\Data    8657271330816 9704357708800 Data
W:       NetworkDrive     \\xxxxx\Winstall 1065067708416 2000263573504 Data
```